Generate dataclass for typing programmatically
How can I express
@dataclass
class Measurements:
    width: int
    height: int
    head_left: int
    head_right: int
    head_width: int
    head_top: int
    head_bottom: int
    head_height: int
    space_above_head: int
    space_below_chin: int
    eyes_to_bottom_edge: int
    eyes_to_top_edge: int


@dataclass
class Constraints:
    width: Bounds = (None, None)
    height: Bounds = (None, None)
    head_left: Bounds = (None, None)
    head_right: Bounds = (None, None)
    head_width: Bounds = (None, None)
    head_top: Bounds = (None, None)
    head_bottom: Bounds = (None, None)
    head_height: Bounds = (None, None)
    space_above_head: Bounds = (None, None)
    space_below_chin: Bounds = (None, None)
    eyes_to_bottom_edge: Bounds = (None, None)
    eyes_to_top_edge: Bounds = (None, None)

without so much duplication?
I've tried
Constraints = dataclasses.make_dataclass('Constraints', [(f.name, Bounds, dataclasses.field(default=(None, None))) for f in dataclasses.fields(Measurements)])

But now because I've defined Constraints like that, I get this typing error when I use Constraint as a type,
def crop(image: npt.NDArray, constraints: Constraints) -> npt.NDArray:
                                          ^


Variable not allowed in type expression

Can anyone think of a better solution?

You need to keep the two similarly defined definitions, because you need static definitions, and the nature of make_dataclass means it cannot be used to make a static definition using runtime values. (The return value of make_dataclass can only be inferred from the types of its arguments, not the values of the arguments.)

@chepner isn't there anything I can do with Python typing to "duplicate" fields but with different types?

It looks like you're trying to make a parameterized dataclass. I'm not sure this is available in Python.

Can you just use a plain vanilla abstract class with a generic parameter, or do you really need the benefits of a dataclass like hash and eq?

@AbhijitSarkar I'm using dataclasses.fields and dataclasses.asdict a lot on these, I also like the fact a dataclass lets me skip implementing init myself.

The best approach I can think of is to have both classes inherit from a generic base dataclass:
@dataclass
class _Base[T]:
    width: T
    height: T
    head_left: T
    head_right: T
    head_width: T
    head_top: T
    head_bottom: T
    head_height: T
    space_above_head: T
    space_below_chin: T
    eyes_to_bottom_edge: T
    eyes_to_top_edge: T

@dataclass
class Measurements(_Base[int]):
    pass

@dataclass
class Constraints(_Base[Bounds]):
    pass

This doesn't handle the default value requirement you added, though. If you need that, you're back to writing everything out by hand or accepting that static tools won't understand what you're doing.

+1 really nice, I didn't know Python could do this. Is there a way to make some attributes have default values in Constraints without letting them have default values in Measurements?

Can the base class be abstract?

@Nils: Well, if you're adding that requirement, then you're back to either writing everything out by hand or accepting that static tools won't understand your code.

@Nils A child data class can override fields in the base data class per the documentation. Keep in mind that fields with default values must be declared after those without, however. Demo here
